# xojo and gnuplot under windows os -- nothing happen

Tags: windows, gnuplot, xojo

Actually, I'm able to execute any gnuplot command under linux os using xojo (see screenshot).

[image]

But, under windows os, nothing happen. Sometimes it give me `errorcode = -2` (shell timeout) and sometimes is nothing (empty result).

Why the same code give different result under different os?

Comment: Since the shell is timing out, did you try increasing the timeout period (or setting it to `-1` for infinite)?

Comment: @AndrewLambert, yes I did. But, it's not works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still can't figure out how to execute gnuplot on windows. The best method (until now) is to execute `gnuplot.exe` directly.

```
dim file as FolderItem = SpecialFolder.Applications.Child("gnuplot").Child("bin").Child("gnuplot.exe")

Shell1.Execute(file.NativePath)
```